# Which Version of Chrome supports window.performance.clearResourceTimings and what is the alternative

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, resource-timing-api

Since when does chrome support window.performance.clearResourceTimings and what is the alternative if it is not available? I can't find any details in the release notes or MDN. There is a clearMarks function but it does not reset the list of items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=495110), `performance.clearResourceTimings` and `performance.setResourceTimingBufferSize` are prefixed in Chrome since v.30.0.1549.0

You should then call `performance.webkitClearResourceTimings` until this bug is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

As it would appear, since version 29. Which was a long, long ways ago. You can view support information for things like these over on [Can I use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=resource-timing).

And as far as [MDN suggests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/clearResourceTimings), it's just `performance.clearResourceTimings()`, not `window.performance.clearResourceTimings()`

Comment: Thanks, weird though because we are getting error messages from chrome 44.0.2403.130 that the  window.performance.clearResourceTimings() method does not exist (is not a function)

Comment: @ElmarWeber AFAIK and as far as [MDN suggests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/clearResourceTimings), it's just `performance.clearResourceTimings()`, not `window.performance.clearResourceTimings()`

Comment: Its window.performance, that's were the API is (although performance may also work). I just downloaded and tested with Chrome 44. It has the API but not the clearResourceTimings method.

Comment: I adjusted the question to be more specific.